# Forcing sync in workbox webpack plugin

Tags: synchronization, progressive-web-apps, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I have a problem with syncing the workbox background sync from webpack plugin. It occurs when I force it as in the tutorial through the Dev Tools:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync

However, when does it occur normally? What is the rule behind it and can I force it programatically?

Thanks in advance,

Grzegorz

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: You can trigger a sync during a test the same was workbox does during testing: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/5e04a622d9c1843a6231e1f835db58ac593f0c1f/test/workbox-google-analytics/static/basic-example/sw.js#L55-L67 (by sending a message to the SW and it triggers a SyncEvent on itself). You [shouldn't use SyncEvent in production code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SyncEvent) though. Or you can [create a Queue directly](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync#advanced_usage) and then call `queue.replayRequests()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

The [`workbox-background-sync` library](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync) will use the underlying Background Sync API, when available.

"[Introducing Background Sync](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync)" gives the best overview of the API that I'm aware of. As per that article:

> You ask for an event to be fired when the user has connectivity, which is immediate if the user already has connectivity. Then, you listen for that event and do whatever you need to do.

So it's up to the browser to determine *when* to fire the `sync` event, based on network connectivity.

When using `workbox-background-sync` on browsers that don't support the Background Sync API, the requests will be retried automatically whenever the service worker starts up, which normally happens when a network request is made from a controlled page, following a period of idleness.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using Chrome, and as far as I know, on this it should work perfectly. If not, it must be something with the system then... because sometimes it just never fires the sync.